# Adding to a key identifier array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append, identifier

I have to have a result which looks like this:

```
            ({1: 'string', 2: 'anotherstring', 3: 'andanother'});
```

It's not limited to three, it could be a variety of lengths (although not above 10).

I'm grabbing data from a php file through a loop:

```
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    var variableName = '<h1>'+item.draw+'</h1>'
                    + '<p>'+item.date+'</p>';

                    output.append(variableName);
            });
```

Basically I would like to have the 'draw' and 'date' variables (eg a string "3123 2010-12-01") put into an array with 'key identifiers' as it's needed by the script. I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I know it has to be inside the loop, and i'm thinking using the .append might have something to do with it?

```
            ({1: '3123 2010-12-01', 2: '6410 2011-04-28', 3: '7129 2012-01-01'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, `map` will be the final object you're looking for. There's probably a better way to write it though.

```
// data looks like: [ {draw: '1', date: 'date1'}, {draw: '2', date: 'date2'} ];
var map = {};
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
    map[v.draw] = v.date;
});
// do what you need with map here
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tscr9/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if I know how to adapt your example. Your output is [{key: 'val', key: 'val'},{key: 'val', key: 'val'}]; and i need an output like ({key: 'value', key: 'value', key: 'value})

Comment: after this block of code, `map` is `{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }`. I added a jsfiddle to the answer

Comment: Marcelo, thanks a lot! The jsfiddle really gave me a clear idea.

Comment: Just one last quick question, the "=" between the key and value in the output is stopping my code from working. Even in the jsfiddle, the result is key=value (and, unfortunately) i need key: value?

Comment: not sure of what you mean. There's no real output in this code, it just creates the `map` object. It might help if you mention how you intend to use `map`

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to use it in this: [spinningWheel](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch) see how the values are in the object with the semicolon separator?

Comment: `map` has the same format as `numbers` in the example on the page you linked. It's just a standard object (in the inline notation, keys and values are separated by colon and pairs are separated by comma). What's the error message?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6916/discussion-between-marcelo-diniz-and-ojame)